# Get user input instead of function's argument

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, input, user-input

Complete novice here playing around with Codeacademy. I was just wondering If I wanted to tweak this function to allow a user input in place of 'd', how would I go about it?

```
def distance_from_zero(d):
    if type(d) == int or type(d) == float:
      print abs(d)
      return abs(d)


    else:
      print "please enter a number"
      return "please enter a number"
```

Comment: Note that (if you insist on type checking at all) it should be `if isinstance(d, (int, float))`, and in 2.x there's also `long`.

Comment: ...to add on to that though, you should eschew type checking in favor of duck typing.

Comment: @JoelCornett, the modern **goose typing** approach is even better -- `isinstance(d, numbers.Real)` in this case (as I'm -- perhaps undeservedly -- credited on wikipedia wrt the term/concept "duck typing", I guess I get a say:-) -- or `numbers.Number` if `complex` is acceptable too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a try/except and make `d=raw_input`:

```
def distance_from_zero(d=raw_input):
        try:
           d = abs(float(d("Enter a number")))  # if it can be a float it can an int
           return d
        except ValueError:
            return "please enter a number"


In [10]: distance_from_zero()
-444
Out[10]: 444.0

In [11]: distance_from_zero()
foo
Out[11]: 'please enter a number'
```

This does work if you want `d` to be inputted from the user which your question seems to want but I would not recommend using it, I would use the following to take input:

```
def distance_from_zero():
    while True:
        try:
            d = abs(float(raw_input("Enter a number")))
            return d
        except ValueError:
            print "please enter a number"
```

To handle possibly taking a number as input or not set d=None and either try to cast anything passed in by the user or take input from the user if no arg is supplied:

```
def distance_from_zero(d=None):
    try:
        d = abs(float(raw_input("Enter a number"))) if d is  None else abs(float(d))
        return d
    except ValueError:
        return "please enter a number"
```

Comment: That seems like an odd way to do it, `raw_input` will be called at definition time.

Comment: **VERY** dubious code: this unconditionally calls `raw_input` at `def` time, once and only once.  Extremely surprising behavior!

Comment: And the second version after the edit fails when called with a number because it tries to call that number -- not an improvement...

Comment: @AlexMartelli, what? It returns a number

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, the Q is very clear that `d` can be a **number**.  In your 2nd version, `d` must be **callable** -- thus it can never be a number.  I see you've now added a third one which doesn't even take any arg, further and further away from the Q.

Comment: @AlexMartelli, *I wanted to tweak this function to allow a user input in place of 'd* , that seems obvious to me that the OP just wants to take input from the user not have a variable passed. My *third attempt* is an example of how  I would take input from a user not an attempt at the question. Lastly I added a fourth  part that will either take a number and if not take input from the user

Comment: @PadraicCunningham well at least you have removed the one with `raw_input` **called** at `def` time -- that's an improvement.  I think to **allow** a user input is different from **forcing** one as in the first two versions you've left, but that's for the OP to disambiguate, I guess.

Comment: @AlexMartelli, yes I did,  neither would be something I would want to use, I still think it was close to what the OP is asking,  the last function is equivalent to what the OP is doing and it also takes input which the OP has requested. Also strictly speaking is  `isinstance(d, numbers.Real)` the same as `isinstance(d, (int,float)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham no, it's broader -- it will be happy with any kind of non-complex number (just like the elsewhere-recommended duck typing would be, and as you're using), including decimals, fractions, and so forth.  That's the **point** of any kind of waterfowl typing: to not needlessly exclude perfectly good numbers (in this case) as type-checking does.

Comment: @AlexMartelli, sound, fair enough I see your point.  In fairness in the OP's code they don't loop  so actually trying to cast `d` if it has been supplied or asking for input once and returning after is a literal interpretation of their code behaves.

Answer (score 0):

You've received answers, but none, it seems to me, that actually does what you ask.  Here's one other possibility that may come closer...:

```
import numbers
def distance_from_zero(d=None):
    while not isinstance(d, numbers.Real):
        try: d = float(raw_input('please enter a number'))
        except ValueError: print('{!r} is not a number'.format(d))
    print(abs(d))
    return abs(d)
```

[Added: a non-number default value for `d` just in case you want to be able to call the function without arguments to **force** user input, rather than just **allow** it as you had phrased the Q; ditto below.]

(If Python 3, use `input` instead of `raw_input`).

This uses "goose typing" -- checks against the abstract base class `numbers.Real`, encompassing all numbers except complex ones (if you like complex numbers too, use `numbers.Number` instead).  It loops zero or more times, until at last `d` is an acceptable number (if you like complex numbers too, use `complex` instead of `float`), then does the work.

(This check against an abstract base class [aka ABC], known as "goose typing", is often though not always preferable to the more general "duck typing" approach I also advocate -- roughly speaking, goose is better than duck when an ABC already exists that fits your needs perfectly, but not otherwise).

This may not be the best architecture, as it conflates two concerns: ensuring that `d` is a number, then doing something with it (in this case, printing and returning its absolute value).  Especially in large scale programming, "separation of concerns" is a great idea -- use separate units (functions, classes, modules, whatever) to deal with separate concerns, put them together at the "orchestration" level where the units are called/used.

This may be a premature concern for your level of programming mastery, but it's not really any harder than conflating the concerns.  I.e, you might have a `def ensure_number(d):` function which just does the `while` loop above then returns `d` when it's an acceptable number, and a **separate** `show_abs` function which just does the `print` and `return` of `abs(d)`.

If you did that, then your "higher level of abstraction" function would be simpler, just delegating to the two other functions...:

```
def distance_from_zero(d=None):
    d = ensure_number(d)
    return show_abs(d)
```

See how much "cleaner" it is, compared to the concerns-conflating approach?  Meaningful name for sub-units (here, simple functions) `ensure_number` and `show_abs` help readability and clarity.

Plus, you may reuse either or both of those "building blocks" if you need them elsewhere in your program, by just calling those lower-level functions again, avoiding the "cardinal sin of copy and paste programming" and respecting the core programming principle of "DRY" ("Don't Repeat Yourself").

Anyway, that's for you to consider.  I think it's never too early in one's programming learning (a life-long endeavor) to get good habits!-)